# Testing MS Team's Tab with different Organization:MS GraphAPI AADSTS65001: user or administrator has not consented to use the application with<app-id>

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a MS Teams tab application that utilizes the SSO and Graph API. It will be published in App Store for commercial use. I had trouble implementing that and ask question here and it got resolved. Here is the question link: ([MS Graph API AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <app-id>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76339976/ms-graph-api-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the))

I am successfully able to test it within my organization and i can retrieve the user list using Graph API.

Before starting the publishing process, I was trying to test it with another organization and it did not work. I am able got the ID Token + Access Token from SSO for other organization but when I am trying to exchange this token to get the Graph API access token It gave me the same error i.e.

```
MS Graph API AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <app-id>
```

Since this not working for that other organization, I am fearing that it won't work if I publish it and will give the same error message.

Since it's working correctly with my organization, I am not sure what I am missing here and why it does not work with the other organization.

**Here is the account Type**:
[image]

**Here is API permission**: I removed all the permission that requires admin consent just to check if that works.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you include what [account type](https://i.imgur.com/Ttb9PCe.png) you selected while registering the application?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, the account type used during app registration is "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Comment: Also when exchanging the Graph API access token, I tried it with 2 different urls: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: The way I am testing is, I am just uploading the manifest package to the other organization. It works till SSO but when my code try to exchange the SSO token with Graph API token, it fails

Comment: Hey @Sridevi, I updated the question with the screenshot of the account type. Thanks

Comment: Could you include what **API permissions** are added when you upload the manifest package to the other organization?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, I have updated the question with the screenshot of the permissions. Also, the scope is - https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read email openid profile offline_access User.ReadBasic.All

Comment: Could you try assigning `User.Read.All` **Delegated** permission in that application and check?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, Initially, it was User.Read.All but it didn't work hence I tried User.ReadBasic.All.

Comment: Even though my app works correctly with my Organization, I am kind of blocked because it does not work with other organizations. I tried to build another app from scratch but that also failed during access_token exchange for Graph API.

Comment: So, I created a brand-new application by following the steps from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs and now it's working. May be something was of in the authentication - redirect URls. But finally, all the blockers are gone now.

Comment: @DeveshTiwari Post your solution approach as an answer so that it can help other community member with same type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** like below:

[image]

Added API permissions:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read email openid profile offline_access User.Read.All
assertion:assertion
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

***Access token got generated successfully like below:***

[image]

The error ***"AADSTS65001: user or administrator has not consented to use the application with"*** usually occurs if you are not granting Admin consent to the API permissions or passing invalid scope.

But in your scenario, you are passing scope correctly and granting Admin consent too. **Hence** re-deploy the Azure AD Application and try.

As per @*Devesh Tiwari*, the issue resolved by creating the Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application.

**Reference:**

[Microsoft-Teams-Samples/samples/tab-sso/nodejs at main · OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples · GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs) by Prithvi-MSFT

**Comment from @Devesh Tiwari**

Actually, the issue was coming because the consent window that was coming for user only had the basic permission grant. It didn't had `User.ReadBasic.All` and `Presence.Read.All` permission. I had a call with MS Dev support and they said, 'Since I need additional permission, I will have to ask the consent again with additional scope' so I had to implement a button that takes the user to browser, ask the consent for additional scope. This is working now for me but the problem is that user have to leave MS teams to give the consent.