# Azure AD Auth, Angular & .NET API with Graph: MSAL.UiRequiredException Fix?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, office365, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I'm faced with the following situation: I have two app registrations in Azure AD - an Angular 17 web app and a REST API with .NET 6. I've set up authentication/authorization through Azure AD. The Angular app calls the API with an access token through MSAL, and everything works as intended.

Recently, I extended my API with a Graph client to draft an Outlook email and return a link that Angular can use to open Outlook and display the email.

The user can then review, manually adjust, and send the email. For this, I extended my API app registration in Azure with the "Mail.ReadWrite" scope and implemented it in C# as follows:

```
  string clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
  string clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
  string tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];

  string[] scopes = { "Mail.ReadWrite" };

  var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };
  var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, userAccessToken, options);

      var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes); 
    
      var requestBody = new Message
      {
          Subject = $"Test",
          Body = new ItemBody
          {
              ContentType = BodyType.Html,
              Content = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,<br/><br/>" +
                        "Test"
          },
          ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
          {
              new() { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = sendDocumentsRequest.Receiver } }
          },
          From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new  EmailAddress { Address = sendDocumentsRequest.Sender } }
      };
    
      // 1. Step: Create E-Mail in drafts folder
      var resultMessage = await graphClient.Me.Messages.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

and this works perfectly for me.

However, all other users receive the following error message:

> 2024-03-20 08:28:50.578 +01:00 [ERR] Error while processing the
> documents in Session ID XXXXX
> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: OnBehalfOfCredential
> authentication failed: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not
> consented to use the application with ID 'XXXXXX' named 'API_DEV'.
> Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
> ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.59.0.0.MsalUiRequiredException:   ErrorCode: invalid_grant Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException:
> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
> application with ID 'XXXX' named 'XXXX'. Send an interactive
> authorization request for this user and resource.
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.HandleTokenRefreshErrorAsync(MsalServiceException
> e, MsalAccessTokenCacheItem cachedAccessTokenItem)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.OnBehalfOfRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters
> commonParameters, AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfParameters
> onBehalfOfParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.ExecuteAsync[T](AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1
> builder, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfCoreAsync(String[]
> scopes, String tenantId, UserAssertion userAssertionValue, Boolean
> enableCae, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(String[]
> scopes, String tenantId, UserAssertion userAssertionValue, Boolean
> enableCae, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Identity.OnBehalfOfCredential.GetTokenInternalAsync(TokenRequestContext
> requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> StatusCode: 400

They don't get a consent prompt. I'm unsure if I already confirmed this consent in a unit test. The users who use the application are assigned to groups associated with the application. It appears the issue is with MSAL.NetCore.4.59.0.0.MsalUiRequiredException. How could I program the call differently? How should I address this issue?

[image]

[image]

=> AdminConsentRequired = no => Microsoft documentation learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/permissions-reference

Comment: Could you include `API permissions` Portal image of your applications by editing your question?

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419373/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application

Comment: @Sridevi Thank you for your reply. I have added the API permissions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/permissions-reference 
In the Microsoft documentation, it is stated that for "Mail.ReadWrite", "AdminConsentRequired" with delegation is "No". Why do I have to change it? I want the user to confirm it.

Comment: `They don't get a consent prompt.` ->This is due to newly add new API permission. User consent prompt shall appear when a user never consent try to sign in your app. I'm afraid you should ask the users who had this issue to **sign in out and sign in again** and see whether the prompt appeared or not. Basically, after the problematic users consent the app, they should be able to work well.

Comment: If you are trying to send mail, "Mail.ReadWrite" permission won't work. You need to assign `Mail.Send` permission.

Comment: @sridevi: "Recently, I extended my API with a Graph client to draft an Outlook email and return a link that Angular can use to open Outlook and display the email.

The user can then review, manually adjust, and send the email. " => The scope is correct and works for me as a user, but as mentioned, it does not work for the others.

Comment: Could you confirm whether you have any admin roles under the tenant?

Comment: @tiny wang:  Are you sure that the dialog is displayed even though I haven't changed anything in the Angular client and the call from GraphClient is happening in the API?"

Comment: anyway we need to have a try because you are not willing to grant admin consent, right? In the meantime, is it possible for us to call Graph API inside the Angular app?

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, admin consent should not be given in my case... Because the user should enter the consent individually... And according to Microsoft, this should also be the default (see the image that I added to the request) => I assume that the problem is that this dialog cannot be automatically displayed in Angular?

Comment: @TinyWang I can edit the app registration and have admin rights for it but not for the organization.

Comment: Could you confirm whether this option is enabled or not in your tenant https://i.imgur.com/qnkIZEt.png?

Comment: first of all, [user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/user-admin-consent-overview#user-consent) should work in Angular app, however, since you are having different app registions(mail.readwrite) API permission is added for the API app but not the one for Angular sign in, so that I'm not sure whether it would affect the grant prompt. If you already test it but no luck, then I'm afraid this can't work for us. Maybe we can try to use only one app registion if admin consent is not an option for us.

Comment: Another option is that, let's use application permission, then using role based access control to check whether the incoming request is allowed to send email.

Comment: @Sridevi yes it is enabled + Allow group owner consent for all group owners
All group owners can allow applications to access data for the groups they own is enabled.

Comment: @Sridevi & tinyWang Thank you for your support. We have now decided to authorize all users through our azure administrator, which has shortened the process. Subsequently, the angular application is capable of opening Outlook based on the logged-in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error usually occurs if you missed granting **consent** to the added permission in either API or Client applications.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran same code by passing token generated without granting consent like this:

[image]

> To resolve the error, make sure to grant **consent** to the added permissions either in `App registration` or in `Enterprise application` where admin will review the permissions and grant accordingly.

In my case, I granted **admin consent** to added permission in API app like this:

[image]

When I ran below code in my environment after granting consent, I got **response** like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Me.SendMail;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace GraphSendMail
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string clientId = "appId";
                string clientSecret = "secret";
                string tenantId = "tenantId";
                string userAccessToken = "token"; // Provide user access token here

                string[] scopes = { "Mail.ReadWrite" };

                var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };
                var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, userAccessToken, options);

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);

                var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
                {
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = "Test",
                        Body = new ItemBody
                        {
                            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                            Content = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,<br/><br/>" +
                                      "Test"
                        },
                        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                        {
                            new Recipient
                            {
                                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                                {
                                    Address = "sri@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" // Provide recipient email here
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                        {
                            new Recipient
                            {
                                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                                {
                                    Address = "sridevi.xxxxxxxx@gmail.com" // Provide cc email here
                                }
                            }
                        }
                                            },
                    SaveToSentItems = true
                };

                await graphClient.Me.SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

                Console.WriteLine("Email successfully sent.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in user's Outlook where mail sent successfully like this:

[image]

If you prefer Administrator to authorize all users by reviewing the permissions, you can check it in `Enterprise application` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We have now decided to authorize all users through the administrator, which has shortened the process. Subsequently, the application is capable of opening Outlook based on the logged-in users.