# How to grant consent during sign in with Microsoft Entra ID (Azure AD)

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-entra-id

I have just started working with **Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID)**, so this might seem like a noob question.

I have a **Dot Net Core 7.0 Web API** application which exposes a REST API for user login.
I have several active user accounts in Azure AD, and I want to sign in to AD using this API.

For this purpose, I am using the Nuget package **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory**, version 5.3.0.

This is my code for signing in:

```
        string clientId = Configuration.GetSection("ClientId").Value;
        string domain = Configuration.GetSection("TokenEndpoint").Value;
        string[] scopes = { "User.ReadWrite.All" };

        IPublicClientApplication app;
        app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(domain).Build();

        try
        {
            var result =  await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userData.email, userData.Password).ExecuteAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            if(ex.InnerException != null){
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
            }
            throw ex;
        }
```

This code is retuning the following error:

```
{
   "error":"invalid_grant",
   "error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '******' named '******'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: ****** Correlation ID: ****** Timestamp: 2024-02-12 08:34:04Z",
   "error_codes":[
      65001
   ],
   "timestamp":"2024-02-12 08:34:04Z",
   "trace_id":"******",
   "correlation_id":"******",
   "suberror":"consent_required"
}
```

I checked on following resources online:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/545439/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-cons
2. [AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <app-id>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419373/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application)
3. [InteractionRequiredAuthError: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549291/interactionrequiredautherror-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-con)
4. ["AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application" occurs when token is acquired on behalf of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314491/aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application?rq=1)

Based on the suggestions made in these resources, I made the following changes

1. In Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> **API permissions**, add the appropriate API permissions for Microsoft Graph (see screenshot below)
2. In In Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> **Authentication**, select both access tokens and ID tokens (see screenshot below)
3. In **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings**, check allow user consent for apps (3rd option)
4. In **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> User settings**, set 'users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf' to Yes

Can you please provide any clue regarding this error?

***Screenshot 1***
[image]

***Screenshot 2***
[image]

Comment: Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> Microsoft Graph -> Delegated -> find `User.ReadWrite.All` -> add -> grant admin consent for xxx

Comment: what you used in your code is a delegated type on app permission, but what you already  have is an Application type of permission. By the way, it's not a good idea to use [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc) flow(get user name and password from request and then sign in) for user sign in. Could you pls help checking if the issue still existed after adding delegated User.ReadWrite.All permission and grant admin consent?

Comment: @TinyWang the sign in process works after adding delegated User.ReadWrite.All permission and granting admin consent

Comment: that will be fine and adding delegated User.ReadWrite.All could solve your exception as expected : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, ***[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)*** library calls Azure AD Graph API which is currently  **deprecated**  and no longer supported.
>
> Alternatively, you can use  ***Microsoft.Identity.Client***  package for generating access token which calls Microsoft Graph API.

The error occurred as you are using permissions of **Application** type with username password flow. Make sure to grant permissions of **Delegated** type while using delegated flows like username password flow, auth code flow etc...

In my case, I registered one Entra ID application and granted *User.ReadWrite.All* permission of **Delegated** type like this:

[image]

To generate the access token via username password flow, I ran below sample c# code installing `Microsoft.Identity.Client` package:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace Sri
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string clientId = "appId";
            string domain = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
            string[] scopes = { "User.ReadWrite.All" };

            IPublicClientApplication app;
            app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(domain).Build();

            try
            {
                UserData userData = new UserData { email = "sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com", Password = "xxxxxxxxx" };
                var result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userData.email, userData.Password).ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Token acquired successfully.");
                Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {result.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                }
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    public class UserData
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, you can **decode** this token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check whether **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims have **valid** values or not:

[image]

Now, you can use this token to call **Microsoft Graph API** requests like listing, creating, updating and deleting Azure AD users.

Comment: Thanks! I am receiving the access token now after adding delegated User.ReadWriteAll permission